# build paths eclipse java j2ee

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I have imported a project (I am very new at this) and I get the following errors:

```
Project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved

Project FST is missing required library: 'C:program Files/Apache Group/Tomcat 4.1/common/lib/servlet.jar'
Project FST is missing required library: 'C:program Files/Apache Group/Tomcat 4.1/common/lib/struts.jar'
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved
Unbound classpath variable: 'TOMCAT_HOME/common/lib/jasper-runtime.jar' in project
Unbound classpath variable: 'TOMCAT_HOME' in project FST
```

I create a variable called TOMCAT_HOME and give it the proper directory ,but  Also, we should change the project classpath to use TOMCAT_HOME rather than the absolute path.
i dont know how to do it  (change the project classpath and the absolute path)
thanks !

Comment: Using absolute paths in the build config is quite problemmatic. We usually put them into properties (we're working with Liferay + Tomcat). Try open the project options and set the required libraries under Build Path to solve the issue temporarily (but think of the others who are working on the same project with you).

Comment: Where did you create the TOMCAT_HOME variable?

Answer (score 0):

To answer somewhat indirectly, if you configure your project build with something like Maven or Gradle, so that you can successfully build the project using the corresponding command-line tool, then it should be quite straightforward to import the project into eclipse using the Maven or Gradle eclipse plugin. I think doing so will be worth whatever trouble it causes you in the short run--just take care to make your project structure conform to the usual project structure that Maven expects or you'll be asking for trouble (it should be no problem to do so for greenfield work).